# Docker error to access private registry (Win)

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I'm try pulling docker container from my private docker registry.

When I run:

```
docker pull 192.168.0.xxx:5000/container
```

The result is:

```
Using default tag: latest Pulling repository 192.168.0.24:5000/asdf
Error while pulling image: Get
http://192.168.0.xxx:5000/v1/repositories/asdf/images: dial tcp
192.168.0.xxx:5000: getsockopt: no route to host
```

The registry is running and working with v2, not v1.

WhenI run:

```
curl -X GET 192.168.0.xxx:5000/v2/_catalog
the connections works and return the correct json
{"repositories":["container","container2","container3","container4"]}
```

I'm running in windows 10 with docker 17.03-1-ce-win12 (stable)

How I can resolve this or force to docker pull to use v2?

Log File:

```
[09:34:01.797][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] proxy >> GET /_ping
[09:34:01.797][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] Dial Hyper-V socket 204fbc3f-f971-4eaa-9d9e-20515954572e:23a432c2-537a-4291-bcb5-d62504644739
[09:34:01.799][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] Successfully dialed Hyper-V socket 204fbc3f-f971-4eaa-9d9e-20515954572e:23a432c2-537a-4291-bcb5-d62504644739
[09:34:01.800][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] proxy << GET /_ping
[09:34:01.841][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] proxy >> POST /v1.27/images/create?fromImage=192.168.0.xxx%3A5000%2Fcontainer&tag=latest
[09:34:01.841][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] Dial Hyper-V socket 204fbc3f-f971-4eaa-9d9e-20515954572e:23a432c2-537a-4291-bcb5-d62504644739
[09:34:01.842][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] Successfully dialed Hyper-V socket 204fbc3f-f971-4eaa-9d9e-20515954572e:23a432c2-537a-4291-bcb5-d62504644739
[09:34:14.358][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] proxy << POST /v1.27/images/create?fromImage=192.168.0.xxx%3A5000%2Fcontainer&tag=latest
```

Update:

```
docker --version
Docker version 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e
```

Comment: Please post the `docker version` command output

Comment: Did you change your network settings after docker was started? E.g. connect to a VPN or WiFi?

Comment: any change in network, all network config is default

Answer (score 0):

I don't found a answer...

But reinstalling docker works.